# Protected inheritance, upcast and conversion operators

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected, explicit-conversion

I am trying to use `protected` inheritance to hide a C-style `struct` members.

By doing this, my derived `class` is now capable to access everything from the `struct` while hiding it from the rest of the program, but it has a cost:
compiler won't allow me anymore to implicit cast from this derived `class` to the base C-style `struct`.

So, to enable again the feature, I added a `public` conversion `operator` in the derived `class`. But here come the weird things:

- first of all, I could not flag the `operator` as `explicit`: compiler starts saying "illigal storage class" on the `struct` type in the `operator` definition.
- without the `explicit` keyword, the compiler still recognize the conversion as inaccessible in the point it is called (i used `static_cast<T>()`).

Any idea?
(I'm using Visual Studio 2010)

Code example:

```
struct DataFromC
{
    int a, b, c;
};

class Data : protected DataFromC
{
public:

    explicit operator DataFromC()
    {
        return (DataFromC)(*this);
    }
};
```

Comment: Show your code with a minimal example.

Comment: It is a poor design. On the one side, you use protected inheritance to hide members of struct, on the other, you want them still be accessible via upcast. Weird. Try to revise your architecture and consider using aggregation instead of inheritance.

Comment: You might find the contrast between [VC++ 2013 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwywka61.aspx) (which detail `explicit`) and [2010 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwywka61%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on conversion operators enlightening (i.e. if you want C++11 features, don't use a 2010 compiler).

Comment: Also note, that conversion operator will return by value, thus it cannot be considered as a cast.

Comment: @Mikhail eh? Casts are conversions and casting to a non-reference type  yields an rvalue. E.g. `(int)6.5`. I'm not sure what you are trying to say

Comment: @Mikhail I've already implemented it via aggregation. The question is: why it should not compile in the other way.

Comment: @quantdev sorry, you are right. Example provided

Comment: @TonyD well thanks, al least the first point is solved, I did not remember that "explicit cast operator" was a C++11 feature

Comment: @MattMcNabb ok, I misused the terminology. I meant that hierarchy upcast and downcast actually do not create any new object, while conversion operator will do.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 It doesn't matter where you are trying to upcast `Data` to `DataFromC`. It is inaccessible at any point.

Comment: @Mikhail yes but why? It should be allowed inside the scope of `Data` since the inheritance is just `protected`.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 It seems like you can declare a getter function like `DataFromC* AsDataFromC() { return this; }` and it will work. Not sure why conversion operator is not working. I recommend not to think too much about it. No one will write this way in a normal program anyway.

Comment: @Mikhail ok, the method as the expected behaviour, that confirms conversion operator must act following some special rule in this case.